# Using WebDriverWait still cannot get the new page_source while performing next_page test

Tags: python, selenium

I am performing next_page test. I use a loop to capature new data while clicking next page. The click function is successful, but it seemes that the `driver.page_source` is not updated after next_page function is performed. As it is still within the loop, the code will run about two times then it can be updated. Just in rare occasion it can succeed.

It will be ok if you use like this:

```
NextPage()
time.sleep(2)
data=driver.page_source
currentpage = GetCurrentPage(data)
```

I understand that driver.page_source will take time to load completely. However, for a large total of page, using `time.sleep()` is time-consuming. Then I tried to use the `WebDriverWait` to wait for the Image class to load(This website has a lot of images each page), but it does not help.

```
page=int(input("Please input page number:"))
if 1< page < 100:
    data=driver.page_source
    currentpage = GetCurrentPage(data)
    while True:
        if currentpage<page:
            try:
                CaptureData(data,file)
                print(currentpage)
                time.sleep(0.5)
                NextPage()
                # time.sleep(1)
                WebDriverWait(driver,5).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME,'J_ItemPicA')))
                data=driver.page_source
                currentpage = GetCurrentPage(data)
                print(currentpage)
            except TimeoutException:
                print("Timeout!")
            except Exception as e:
                print("Unexpected error!",e)
                break
        else:
            print('testa')
            CaptureData(data,file)
            break
elif page ==1:
    CaptureData(driver.page_source,file)
```

At most times, the output of above code will be like:

```
Please input page number: 2
1
1
1
2
testa
```

In case you may need the GetCurrentPage code:

```
def GetCurrentPage(data):
    soup=BeautifulSoup(data,'lxml')
    comments = soup.find_all("li", class_="item active")
    cp = re.findall('\d', comments[0].text)
    currentpage = int(''.join(cp))
    return currentpage
```

The link is [there](https://s.taobao.com/search?q=it&imgfile=&commend=all&ssid=s5-e&search_type=item&sourceId=tb.index&spm=a21bo.2017.201856-taobao-item.1&ie=utf8&initiative_id=tbindexz_20170306&sort=default&bcoffset=3&ntoffset=3&p4ppushleft=1%2C48&s=44), but it is with Chinese.

Any other suggestions please?
Thanks a million.

Comment: can you share the link of the webpage from where you are downloading data if it is a public website?

Comment: @thebadguy Updated the link. Sorry it is with Chinese not English.

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem myself.

Use `WebDriverWait`. Get the current page, then decide if is equal to the former page plus 1.

Here is the code:

```
   try:
        CaptureData(data, file)
        print(currentpage)
        time.sleep(0.5)
        NextPage()
        # time.sleep(2)
        element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.text_to_be_present_in_element(
            (By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#mainsrp-pager > div > div > div > ul > li.item.active'),
            str(int(currentpage) + 1)))
        if element:
            data = driver.page_source
            currentpage = GetCurrentPage(data)
            print(currentpage)
```